# jQuery Countdown not working with all versions of IE

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, counter, countdown

I am using jquery countdown in one of rails project with following code -

```
var timeoff = new Date("#{time_format(auction.end_time)}");
$("#myDivId .timerContent").countdown({until : timeoff, onExpiry:applySold, compact : true, layout : '', serverSync: serverTime });
```

and serverTime methods has -

```
 function serverTime(){
    $.get("/server_time","", function(data){
      time = new Date(data);
    }, "text");
  return time;
```

}

This code works very well with firefox, safari and chrome but doesn't work in IE.
In IE it renders this - Nan:NaN:NaN

What might be causing this ?

P.S. In above code i at the point of 
        var timeoff = new Date("#{time_format(auction.end_time)}");

i have time format as - "2011-07-07T00:00:00+05:30"

and my Doc type is set as -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Can't answer properly unless I see the countdown code, but my guess is that the variables which hold the numbers need `parseInt()` wrapped around them

Comment: I am using jquery countdown plugin -http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html 
which gives .countdown method.

Comment: `time` within the `serverTime()` method should always be undefined, if I'm not mistaken. `$.get` asynchronously loads data and assigns it to time in a callback, while `time has been returned already before it's set.

Comment: can $.get cause browser compatibility? I have same code working in FF and Chrome, only IE is culprit.
Thanks, trying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact SAme ISSUE, im using Date.parse($(".time").html) which outputs fine for both IE and FF... When I test this in plain HTML it works and counts down for BOTH BROWSERS!! But Its seems RUBY rials.js or the load order of the JS's are conflicting with IE..!!!!!

Test this page at www.scratch22.net/testing in BOTH IE and FIREFIOX!! works fine!! but not from within an actual rails app!!

**EDIT**
So I tried many many different answers from many different places and could only get one to work for comparing datetime with timezone in javascript for IE

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Time.now
        => 2011-07-14 08:55:26 +1000 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > Time.now.to_s
        => "2011-07-14 08:55:30 +1000" 
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > Time.now.to_datetime.to_s 
        => "2011-07-14T08:55:51+10:00"
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > Time.now.to_formatted_s 
        => "2011-07-14T08:56:18+10:00"
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > Time.now.to_datetime
        => Thu, 14 Jul 2011 08:55:35 +1000
```

** I originally had <%= Time.now.to_datetime %> and didnt realise that this returns a different string format when printing out to a page **

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > Time.now.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)
        => "Thu, 14 Jul 2011 08:57:26 +1000"
```

The last Was the only time format with timezone that I could get IE to work with as a number... I got rid of the Parse aswell...

All up what I wanted to do was return the time between now and when a price should drop,
and show a countdown...

Resulting JS was something like

```
    now = new Date().getTime(); // Thu, 14 Jul 2011 07:57:26 +1000
    drops_in = new Date("Thu, 14 Jul 2011 08:57:26 +1000").getTime(); //1 hour in future
    countdown = drops - now;
    $(".counter_holder").html(format_time(countdown)); // 00:35:25
```

inside of a interval updating every 500 milliseconds

The lesson learnt...

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > Time.now.to_datetime
```

**is not** the same as

<%= Time.now.to_datetime %>

Use <%= **Time.now.to_formatted_s(:rcf822)** %> instead

Comment: I found the solutions by changing date formats. My older date formate included timezone as well and that was causing Date.new() to not create the Date object.
I would suggest try running below code in IE console.
   Date.parse($(".time").html).to_s
to check if this gives you correct date object.